# How to call and close while the called executable is running?

Tags: batch-file, call

In a batch file when you call an executable your prompt window stays open. How to hide it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can put "Start" before the name of the executable. This will start the executable and exit without waiting for it to finish.

For example,

```
notepad.exe
exit
```

will not close the command prompt window until notepad is closed.

```
start notepad.exe
exit
```

will exit immediately without waiting.

Of course, if subsequent actions in the batch file are dependent on the executable finishing then this will be of no use to you.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12848306/731081) for more detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple little utility .exe files [here](http://www.paulsadowski.com/WSH/cmdprogs.htm) which allow you to maximize/minimize/restore shell windows.