# Batch script that executes all programs in a directory?

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch file that will open all files in D:\software.

I have searched the internet but could not find anything. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You're not going to just *find* a script like that, you need to *write* one.  Just iterate through the directory with a `FOR` loop, then run each program.  I sure hope there aren't a lot of programs in that directory, though...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should be able to find a number of resources by searching on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909012/windows-batch-script-launch-program-and-exit-console, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file

Comment: Welcome!  Here is a quick search with relevant results.  https://www.google.com/#q=dos+open+all+files+in+a+folder

Answer (score 1):

Here's a batch script that will navigate to `D:\software` and execute all **programs** (*.exe):

**executeAll.cmd**

```
cd D:\software
for %%f in (*.exe) do (
    echo %%~nf
    start "" "%%f"
)
exit
```

If you want the script to open **all files**, change the first line to

```
for %%f in (*.*) do (
```

In order to run the batch file, you'll need to save it with the proper extension. In Notepad, this is trivial but not obvious: when you save the file, put quotes around the filename + extension, like `"executeAll.cmd"`. Otherwise, it will be saved with a .txt extension like `executeAll.cmd.txt`.

Comment: thats not working :( when i use the .exe line he will open widows vieuwer

Comment: im using windows 8.1 or is that the problem?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1 too so that's not it. Did you save the batch file with the correct extension? I updated my answer with instructions.

Comment: @MartijnterArkel - It almost sounds like you have .exe files associated with Windows Viewer.

Comment: If you used the `*.*` the script will open every file wih the default associated program.  For example `.TXT` opens with `Notepad.exe` unless you make the script open the file(s) with another program.  For example: `C:\Apps\Notepad++.EXE myfile.txt` will open the Text file in Notepad++.