# How can i close a .bat file after opening it

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

i'm trying to make a loading bar batch file that opens a .exe (HDDLED.exe) file, but it will stay open until i close the .exe file, i have searched the internet but what i could find is this: start"" " , exit , tskill cmd.exe , and some other stuff, but it will not work, here's the code:

```
@echo off
color 0a
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo                                 =   0 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo []                              =   5 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][]                            =  15 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][][]                          =  23 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][][][]                        =  30 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][][][][]                      =  38 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][][][][]                      =  42 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][][][][][]                    =  45 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][][][][][][]                  =  48 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][][][][][][][]                =  50 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][][][][][][][][]              =  56 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][][][][][][][][][]            =  63 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][][][][][][][][][][]          =  69 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][][][][][][][][][][][]        =  75 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][][][][][][][][][][][][]      =  79 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][][][][][][][][][][][][][]    =  86 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]  =  90 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]  =  96 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo         Welcome to HDDLED...
echo ---------------------------------------
echo [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]= 100 ]
echo ---------------------------------------


ping localhost -n 2 >nul
pause

pushd %~dp0
HDDLED.exe
popd"

*insert exit code here*
```

[here's where i got the code](http://www.instructables.com/id/Loading-effect-in-batch/%22Here's%20where%20i%20got%20the%20code...),

[And here's where i got the HDDLED.exe file](https://youtu.be/NO_gqbE3e54%22and%20here's%20where%20i%20got%20the%20HDDLED.exe%22).

ps, sorry for my bad english, i'm not a native speaker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch script launch program and exit console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909012/windows-batch-script-launch-program-and-exit-console)

Comment: Have you perhaps tried `exit`?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the command block

```
pushd %~dp0
HDDLED.exe
popd"
```

with the completely wrong `"` in last line by

```
start "HDDLED" /D"%~dp0" HDDLED.exe
```

The command **START** starts a new process with setting the directory of the batch file as current directory before starting `HDDLED.exe`. This new process running parallel to command process processing the batch file is also a command process if `HDDLED.exe` is a console application and not a Windows GUI application. In this case the new command process opens also a console window with title `HDDLED` as specified as first parameter in double quotes.

Run in a command prompt window `start /?` to get output the help explaining this command and its options.

After **START** was executed the Windows command interpreter `cmd.exe` immediately continues processing the batch file. The batch file processing exits with no more lines in batch file. This means the command process exits if the batch file was double clicked for execution.

I suggest further to replace `ping` by `%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe` to make your batch file independent on the values of the environment variables `PATHEXT` and `PATH`.

I suppose `localhost` is not really specified in your batch file as in this case `-n 1` would not make sense at all because the echo request is always immediately answered by local host computer.

An advice: You should replace the entire batch code above output of `Welcome to HDDLED...` by a command block using either a **FOR** loop with `for /L %%I in (1,1,100) do (...)` or a label with **GOTO** command and `set /A Number+=1`. Run in a command prompt window `for /?` and `goto /?` and `set /?` for help on those 3 commands. A **FOR** loop can be broken at any time by jumping with command **GOTO** to a label below the **FOR** loop.